# How to enable Acer Aspire One 725 0802 touchpad & F Keys?

Tags: linux, windows, keyboard, touchpad, acer

I recently tried to install the Elementary Luna OS using Unetbootin. Instead of installing to a USB or CD to boot from, I installed the OS to the hard drive.

It seemed to install fine, the BIOS showed the option to boot from either Windows 7 or the UNetbootin. Selecting the latter, would boot up the Elementary Luna OS, but immediately, the touchpad on the PC mentioned in the subject line, was disabled. Prior to doing any of this, the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys and a few of the keys in the top left corner of the keyboard, were disabled too. So, any accidental presses of <kbd>FN</kbd> and the enable/disable the touchpad key, were essentially impossible.

Even going back into Windows 7, and enabling/disabling the touchpad, updating/installing the/new drivers, and installing Windows updates still left the touchpad disabled.

I deleted/uninstalled everything to do with the Linux OS and only have Windows installed. It should be noted that booting in Safe Mode, the touchpad works fine and the cursor moves as normal.

Would the installation of the Linux OS have disabled the touchpad? Is there any way of reverting the touchpad back to usable state?

Answer (score 0):

Touchpad works, but xorg is confused about its initial state, which is disabled by default. Just press Fn+F7 before entering into X and it will work perfectly.

Comment: What does Fn+F7 represent, please?